# Is $U+V$ equivalent to $U \cup V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$U$ und $V$ are subspaces of a $R^n$

Is $U+V$ equivalent to $U \cup V$?

Additional question:
If I compare basis' instead of subspaces it would be correct? There is a basis(U+V), that is equivalent to a basis($U \cup V$) 
?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in general $U \cup V$ isn't a subspace: If there are $u \in U \setminus V$ and $v \in V \setminus U$ then $u+v \not\in U \cup V$. Hence $U \cup V$ is a subspace iff $U \subseteq V$ or $ V \subseteq U$.

$U+V$ is by definition the smallest subspace containing $U$ and $V$, that is $U+V = {\rm span}\, (U \cup V)$.

Comment: Ok, but if compare basis' instead of subspaces it would be correct?
There is a basis(U+V), that is equivalent to a basis($U \cup V)$

Comment: @SuperNova: $U \cup V$ is not a linear space, and thus has no concept of basis. However, if you take the union of a basis of U and a basis of V, you get a spanning set of U+V. (Which is a basis if it doesn't have too many elements)

Answer (score 2):

No. $U+V$ is usually strictly bigger than the union (which is usually not even a subspace). Take for example $U=\mathbb{R}\oplus \{0\}$, $V=\{0\}\oplus \mathbb{R}$. Then $U+V=\mathbb{R^2}$, but the union does not contain $(1,1)$.

We can prove more: over infinite field (such as $\mathbb{R}$), no finite union of proper subspaces can be a full space. Thus, for any finite collection of subspaces such that none contains all the others, the union won't be a subspace.

On the other hand, it's possible for spaces over finite fields. Take $\mathbb{F}_2^2$ and $U=\langle(0,1)\rangle$, $V=\langle(1,0)\rangle$, $W=\langle(1,1)\rangle$. Then $U\cup V\cup W=U+V+W=\mathbb{F}_2^2$.

Answer (score 2):

It need not be.

Example: $U = \{(x,0): x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, and $V = \{(0,y): y \in \mathbb{R}\}$, then $U + V = \mathbb{R}^2$, but $U\cup V \neq \mathbb{R}^2$